# "zsh: killed" output in terminal, when trying to run a FHIR Validator (Java)

Tags: java, terminal, jar, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to run the FHIR Validator through terminal, but the process seems to get killed everytime I try to run it.

I'm using the following command:

```
java -Xmx46144m -jar validator_cli.jar generatedTest2.xml -version 3.0 -bundle Patient:0 http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/ips/StructureDefinition/Patient-uv-ips
```

The validator is available here:
https://github.com/hapifhir/org.hl7.fhir.core/releases/latest/download/validator_cli.jar

Here is the log from the terminal (macOS):

```
user@myMac assets % java -Xmx46144m -jar validator_cli.jar generatedTest2.xml -version 3.0 -bundle Patient:0 http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/ips/StructureDefinition/Patient-uv-ips

FHIR Validation tool Version 5.2.20 (Git# af05868a82bf). Built 2021-01-25T15:02:44.742Z (81 days old)
  Java:   15.0.1 from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home on x86_64 (64bit). 46144MB available
  Paths:  Current = /Users/user/Documents/implementation/assets, Package Cache = /Users/user/.fhir/packages
  Params: generatedTest2.xml -version 3.0 -bundle Patient:0 http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/ips/StructureDefinition/Patient-uv-ips
Loading
  Load FHIR v3.0 from hl7.fhir.r3.core#3.0.2 - 4017 resources (00:06.0267)
  Load hl7.terminology#2.0.0 - 3749 resources (00:01.0567)
  Terminology server http://tx.fhir.org - Version 1.9.371 (00:02.0288)
  Get set...  go (00:01.0248)
Validating
  Validate generatedTest2.xmlzsh: killed     java -Xmx46144m -jar validator_cli.jar generatedTest2.xml -version 3.0 -bundl
```

I'm using the -Xmx46144m addition, since otherwise I was receiving the "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" Error.

Is there an option, which can help me, so that my process is not being killed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also tried with the -d64 flag, since is important to tell the JVM to run in 64-bit mode, but I'm getting the following: "Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."

Comment: you are running the 64bit jvm - that's in the log output. How much physical memory do you have?

Comment: @GrahameGrieve I have 8 GB in total

Comment: Is most of that memory available to the process?  With only 8GB, you won't be able to have *anything* else running in parallel.  (The validator uses a lot of memory.)

Comment: it should only need about 1.5 GB. So try specifying something around 2GB